# Como conectar SQLServer 2014 con java

Tags: java, sql-server

Estoy intentando conectarme con java con el ide eclipse, pero me bota este error.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se pudo realizar
>   la conexión TCP/IP al host localhost, puerto 1433. Error: "connect
>   timed out. Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay
>   una instancia de SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las
>   conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall
>   bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto.".

```
public class SQLServerConexion {

public static Connection getConexion() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbUsuarios;integratedSecurity=true;");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

Tengo el .jar de sql en WEB-INF - lib "sqljdbc42.jar", pero igual me sale ese error, sera que tengo que hacer algo mas, porque me estoy conectando con autenticacion con window.

Ya habilite el puerto TCP 1433 de IPAII.